# cx_FreezeでAttributeErrorが出る。：module 'setuptools._distutils.command' has no attribute 'install'

Tags: python, anaconda, setuptools, cx-freeze

私はpyautoguiを使って、GUIの自動化プログラムを作成しました。
`python main.py`をコマンドラインで実行すると作動します。
プログラムの構成は以下の通りです。

```
zoom_auto_controller_app/main.py
zoom_auto_controller_app/setup.py
zoom_auto_controller_app/zoom_controller
zoom_controller/controller
zoom_controller/models
zoom_controller/templates
zoom_controller/views
```

私はこのアプリをcx_Freezeを用いてexe化し、配布しようと考えました。
cx_Freezeの最初のステップ、`python setup.py build`は成功しました。
しかし、次のステップ、`python setup.py bdist_msi`でAttributeerrorが出ます。
そのエラーメッセージは以下の通りです。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 77, in <module>
    shortcutDir="ZoomProgramMenu",
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 342, in setup
    distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 986, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\windist.py", line 
390, in run
    install = self.reinitialize_command('install', reinit_subcommands = 1)     
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 207, in reinitialize_command
    cmd = _Command.reinitialize_command(self, command, reinit_subcommands)     
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 306, in reinitialize_command
    reinit_subcommands)
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 939, in reinitialize_command
    command = self.get_command_obj(command_name)
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\dist.py", line 859, in get_command_obj
    cmd_obj = self.command_obj[command] = klass(self)
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 172, in __init__
    _Command.__init__(self, dist)
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\setuptools\_distutils\cmd.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.initialize_options()
  File "C:\Users\kohei\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\dist.py", line 248, in initialize_options
    distutils.command.install.install.initialize_options(self)
AttributeError: module 'setuptools._distutils.command' has no attribute 'install'
```

setup.pyの内容も以下に示します。

```
import os
import sys

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'C:\\Users\\kohei\\anaconda3\\tcl\\tcl8.6'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'C:\\Users\\kohei\\anaconda3\\tcl\\tk8.6'

base = None
if sys.platform == "win32":
    base = "Win32GUI"

packages = [
    "csv",
    "datetime",
    "os",
    "pathlib",
    "pyautogui",
    "string",
    "subprocess",
    "termcolor",
    "time",
    "xlrd",
]

excludes = [
    "lxml",
    "matplotlib",
    "numpy",
    "pandas",
    "tkinter",
]

includes = [
    'zoom_controller',
    'zoom_controller.models',
    'zoom_controller.controller',
    'zoom_controller.templates',
    'zoom_controller.views',
    ]

build_exe_options = {
    "packages":packages,
    "excludes":excludes,
    "includes":includes,
}

directory_table = [
(
    "ProgramMenuFolder",
    "TARGETDIR",
    ".",
),
(
    "ZoomProgramMenu",
    "ProgramMenuFolder",
    "ZoomAutomator",
),
                ]

msi_data = {
    "Directory": directory_table,
}

setup(
    name = "zoom_auto_controller_app",
    version = "1.1.0",
    description = "Zoom Automator",
    options = {'build_exe': build_exe_options,
                'bdist_msi': {'data': msi_data}},
    executables = [
        Executable(
            'main.py',
            base=base,
            shortcutName="ZoomAutomator",
            shortcutDir="ZoomProgramMenu",
        )
    ])
```

なぜエラーが起こるのかわかりません。
是非解決法を教えていただきたいです。
いかなるコメントもお待ちしております。

なお、エラーに関わってそうなパッケージのバージョンは以下です。

- cx_Freeze-6.2
- setuptools-50.0.0

Comment: 英語サイトでの[同件質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63696586/9014308)

Comment: 何か問題が再現出来て公開しても良い小さなサンプルプログラムを作って掲載してみてはどうでしょう？ それを作る過程で発生条件とか分かるかもしれませんし。